# how to get the currently displayed controller in anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, popupwindow

I need to get the currently displayed controller anywhere, but all the information points to the following method

```
// 获取当前显示的Controller
+ (UIViewController *)currentViewController {
    // Find best view controller
    UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    return [self findBestViewController:viewController];
}

+ (UIViewController*)findBestViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    if (vc.presentedViewController) {
        return [self findBestViewController:vc.presentedViewController];
    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {
        UISplitViewController* svc = (UISplitViewController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
        return [self findBestViewController:svc.viewControllers.lastObject];
        else
        return vc;
    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* svc = (UINavigationController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
        return [self findBestViewController:svc.topViewController];
        else
        return vc;
    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* svc = (UITabBarController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
        return [self findBestViewController:svc.selectedViewController];
        else
        return vc;
    } else {
        return vc;
    }
}
```

The obtained controller is no problem to jump, such as push and present. But if I need to know the class of the currently displayed controller, if the current controller contains sub-controllers, I ca n’t know which one is currently displayed, causing the requirements corresponding to my page and popup to be unrealizable

Comment: Do you mean `childViewControllers`?

Comment: YES, Each controller may have childViewControllers. I do n’t know how to get the currently displayed childController.@RomanPodymov

Comment: So, `self.childViewControllers[self.childViewControllers.count - 1]` is currently visible controller, right?

Comment: This works for me some time. just only after I took over the life cycle of childViewControllers. if not ,this useless to me @RomanPodymov

Comment: Do you store a reference to the latest controller that you added with `addChildViewController`? Can you share more code?

Comment: @RomanPodymov NO,I don't store a reference to the latest controller.  
`[self.scrollView addSubview:vc.view];
        [self addChildViewController:vc];
        [vc.view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.left.equalTo(self.scrollView).offset([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * realIndex);
            make.width.height.equalTo(self.scrollView);
            make.top.equalTo(self.scrollView);
        }];` just like this method.then useless to me

Comment: @RomanPodymov  In other words, when the controller is loaded for the first time, the childController will not be called viewWillAppear、viewDidAppear again. the childControllers will be a fixed order Array

Comment: @RomanPodymov  Have any method can get currentController  unrelated current application structure

Comment: So, you have a `UIScrollView` instance, you add different subviews to it and you want to know what subview is currently visible, right?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Thanks in advance for your patience，YES,Although this demand is strange，In other words, which controller the view currently displayed on the screen belongs to, what method can be used to find the current view without reference to the currently displayed view。It is really difficult or impossible to obtain with my current knowledge. I want to see if anyone knows or definitely tells me that it cannot be achieved.

Comment: I think currently there is no such function in iOS.